# Ternary operator error, on valid if: else; statement

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I have a valid if: else; code section as follows:

```
var obj = new Object();
if(Validation.IsDirectory(fileName))
{
   obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(FilePath));
}
else
{
   obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(FileName));
}
```

The above generates no error. But, if I translate this to a shorthand if statement, like below:

```
Validation.IsDirectory(fileName) ? obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(FilePath)) : obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(FileName));
```

I get the error:

**[Error    CS0201](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0201)  Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement**

In that error documentation it clearly states that:

> ...Invalid statement is any line or series of lines ending in a
> semicolon that does not represent an **assignment (=)**, **method call ()**,
> new, -- or ++ operation.

But out of my first 3 statements the **first is a method call** and the **last two are assignment operations**.

So, why am I receiving this error? And how do I write this statement as a shorthand if statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make the assignment inside the ternary operator. This operator is used in expressions and yields a value that you then can assign. Also, since now we have a single assignment, we can merge this with the declaration.

(Btw., the initialization expression `new Object()` in your declaration is superfluous, as the following statements replace this object anyway. `object obj;` would suffice.)

```cs
object obj = Validation.IsDirectory(fileName)
    ? Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(FilePath))
    : Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(FileName));
```

However, you can simplify this further and call the Activator only once by applying the ternary operator the `Type` arguments only:

```cs
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(
    Validation.IsDirectory(fileName) ? typeof(FilePath) : typeof(FileName)
);
```

---

It would be easier to work with `FilePath` and `FileName` if they had a common base class that you would use instead of `object`. The same pattern is used in  the [System.IO Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io?view=net-6.0) namespace with the [DirectoryInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-6.0) and the [FileInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-6.0). Both derive from [System.IO.FileSystemInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-6.0) and share common members like `Name`, `FullName` or `Delete()`.

Comment: It appears my mistake was a misunderstanding of the ternary operator. And I will follow your common base class suggestion, as that had not occurred to me.

Answer (score 2):

The [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) is **not** "a shorthand if statement".  The ternary operator is an *expression* which *resolves to a value*.

In your attempt it would be structurally similar to a line of code which is nothing more than a value:

```
4;
```

This line of code is not a statement, hence the error.

You can use the *result* of the expression as part of a statement.  For example:

```
var x = 4;
```

Or in your case:

```
var x = someTernaryExpression;
```

Which would be:

```
var obj = Validation.IsDirectory(fileName) ? Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(FilePath)) : Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(FileName));
```

---

In short...

- When you want to conditionally perform an operation, use `if`.
- When you want to conditionally *resolve to a value inline*, use `?:`.

Comment: I misunderstood the ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

You perform the assignment **as a result of** (i.e. after) the ternary operator

```
obj = Validation.IsDirectory(fileName) ? Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(FilePath)) : Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(FileName));
```

The ternary operator does the check and returns the first value when `true`, otherwise it returns the second value.

The returned value can then be assigned normally.